# Promise result value is unknown in generic function type

Tags: typescript, function, generics, promise, async-await

I'm trying to type a generic decorator/wrapper function for a function that returns a Promise.

I've tried this code, but it returns `Promise<unknown>` on the `callFetch` function, when I'm expecting it to return `Promise<{ param: string; userId: number }>`, which is the return type of `callAPI`.

```js
const callAPI = (param: string, userId: number) => Promise.resolve({ param, userId });

function wrappedFunctions() {
  const userId = 1;
  // hypothetical refetch function
  const refetch = () => {};

  const wrapAction = <T extends (...args: any[]) => Promise<R>, R>(
    callback: T,
  ): ((...args: Parameters<T>) => Promise<R>) => async (...args: Parameters<T>) => {
    const response = await callback(...args);
    refetch();
    return response;
  };

  // returns Promise<unknown>
  // expect Promise<{ param: string; userId: number }>
  const callFetch = wrapAction((param: string) => callAPI(param, userId));

  return {
    callFetch,
  };
}
```

Here is a [codesandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBMCGAbRBBACgSRgXhgCgAd4AneAWwC4ZpiBLMAcwBoYBXCAU2IwBMqxWZAEZcAlDgB8MNMRBlanAHTEOEEIgBuHPAG8YRUmRbsuvGAF9RAbgBQNgGaswwKLXAwA7qQIEOPAGJOLm6QeOI6NjBw4NBsnNw8ODAAjLZRAPTpMAAWAJ4EIFDZHK4IiDAq9iXA2TCOzq7gkdGQsJXVtbhhkjA65rbNoK2e3ijB7rgAPAAqMBwAHlAcYDwQ+IobJAwQVPBguQDaALri2FIycgockwBKEix3eM1RZYhC8MAA1lTTTM2iVDweA2ii2O2kJHIJS4EBmElO51k8k4t3hPXgEFyznWm2I2yoaEhZGhxFh0zRZ16zxasRUEAKkA4SXgHngtFgr3eX2BuO21mp7SgNTCaSiFRKrGIYHF9JiHFF-TsGSyKigksg0iRV0mTk+YBAHjAEmamTm818Lk1lxROgM5CoNHoDCscVMfBgAmEXAsxpeMQ5SEQ-g6SS88AIY0aYCBdso1CgdEYCLggfQGEIROM8V4on5zVV6qpYpTyGDQuyfyiivMNiAA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that `R` template variable depends on `T` content.

But in your case, instead of extending the whole callback, you can have 2 separate template variables: one for args, another for the return value:

*Example:*

```
const wrapAction = <A extends unknown[], R>(
    callback: (...args: A) => Promise<R>,
): ((...args: A) => Promise<R>) => async (...args) => {
    const response = await callback(...args);
    refetch();
    return response;
};

const callFetch = wrapAction((param: string) => callAPI(param, userId));
```

`A` template variable will extract a list of arguments (e.g. `[param: string]`) and `R` promise return type (e.g. `{ param: string; userId: number; }`).